# Android bottom sheet not going down

Tags: android

I am adding a bottom sheet to my co-ordinator layout, but it is not going down(below the screen), it overlaps over the visible content on the screen. I have tried removing couple of elements but it doesn't work!

Here is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_200"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_collapsing_toolbar_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:scaleX="1.2"
                android:scaleY="1.2"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="136dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_title_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_date_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/date_radius"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:alpha="0.4"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
                        android:tint="@android:color/black"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_runtime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_vote"
                            style="?attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:alpha="0.8"
                            android:isIndicator="true"
                            android:numStars="10"
                            android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                            android:stepSize="0.1"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                        android:text="@string/overview"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_overview_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                        android:text="@string/top_cast"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_cast_reycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_show_more_cast"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/show_more_cast"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_anchor_image"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="174dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fragment_detail_app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_favourites_fab"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_48dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add `app:behavior_hideable="true"` to your layout, so it will look like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="true">
```

---

**behavior_hideable:** Whether this bottom sheet can be hidden by dragging it further downwards May be a boolean value, such as "true" or "false".

Source: [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by setting `app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"` (Don't know if it is the best practice, but it gets the job done)